# Rails not parsing body of my request to params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Using Rails version 4.2.3

Postman generated request:

```
POST /resources.json HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxx.xx:3000
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 68deca0d-7c6f-0948-cf2c-0f75db4519e6
    
{ 
    "company": { 
        "name": "acme", 
        "address": "123 Carrot Street" 
    } 
}
```

Inspection of params:

```
{
    "controller" => "resources", 
    "action" => "create", 
    "format" => "json"
}
```

Inspection of request.body.read:

```
{ 
    "company": { 
        "name": "acme", 
        "address": "123 Carrot Street" 
    } 
}
```

I couldn't think off where this can go wrong, please give me a direction to dig

Comment: Are you using strong params? or you are just calling `params` in your controller?

Comment: @Orlando yes I am using strong parameters. I even commented out the line and tried to use simply params.permit(:company). Still get no data from body in the params

Comment: I have this same issue with Rails v5.0.0 and it's driving me insane. Any luck so far?

Comment: @PrestonLee It was so long ago so I don't remember the details, but It had something to do with the parameter white list. Please check all possible points of filtering.